# AssemblyLoadException in PostSharp on release build

Tags: json.net, postsharp

I have a couple of projects that all include the json.net 6.0.3 NuGet package. When I add:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
```

I get the following error when building:

> 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: Unhandled exception
>   (3.1.48.0, 32 bit, CLR 4.5, Release):
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyLoadException: Cannot find assembly
>   'newtonsoft.json, version=4.5.0.0, culture=neutral,
>   publickeytoken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'. [Version mismatch]
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: ============
>   PostSharp Assembly Loading Log ===================
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG: Finding the
>   assembly with binding identity 'newtonsoft.json, version=4.5.0.0,
>   culture=neutral, publickeytoken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG: Found file
>   'F:\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll' with
>   identity 'newtonsoft.json, version=6.0.0.0, culture=neutral,
>   publickeytoken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorarchitecture=msil'.
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG: Reference
>   mismatch for
>   'F:\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.3\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
>   [VersionMismatch]. 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099:
>   LOG: Probing location
>   'C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\3.1.48\bin.Release\Newtonsoft.Json.exe'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found]. 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG:
>   Probing location
>   'C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\3.1.48\bin.Release\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found]. 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG:
>   Probing location
>   'C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\3.1.48\bin.Release\Newtonsoft.Json.winmd'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found]. 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG:
>   Probing location 'F:\bin\release\TwinkyTalk\Newtonsoft.Json.exe'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found]. 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG:
>   Found file 'F:\bin\release\TwinkyTalk\Newtonsoft.Json.dll' with
>   identity 'newtonsoft.json, version=6.0.0.0, culture=neutral,
>   publickeytoken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorarchitecture=msil'.
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG: Reference
>   mismatch for 'F:\bin\release\TwinkyTalk\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
>   [VersionMismatch]. 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099:
>   LOG: Probing location
>   'F:\bin\release\TwinkyTalk\Newtonsoft.Json.winmd' because this
>   directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG: Probing
>   location 'F:\TwinkyTalk\obj\Release\Newtonsoft.Json.exe' because this
>   directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG: Probing
>   location 'F:\TwinkyTalk\obj\Release\Newtonsoft.Json.dll' because this
>   directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not Found].
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG: Probing
>   location 'F:\TwinkyTalk\obj\Release\Newtonsoft.Json.winmd' because
>   this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File Not
>   Found]. 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG: Probing
>   location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Newtonsoft.Json.exe'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found]. 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG:
>   Probing location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found]. 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG:
>   Probing location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Newtonsoft.Json.winmd'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found]. 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG:
>   Probing location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\Newtonsoft.Json.exe'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found]. 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG:
>   Probing location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\Newtonsoft.Json.dll'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found]. 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG:
>   Probing location 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5.1\Facades\Newtonsoft.Json.winmd'
>   because this directory was explicitly added to the search path [File
>   Not Found]. 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG:
>   Looking in GAC for Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=x86.
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG: Looking in GAC
>   for Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=msil.
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: LOG: Looking in GAC
>   for Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed. 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj :
>   error PS0099: LOG: The assembly 'newtonsoft.json, version=4.5.0.0,
>   culture=neutral, publickeytoken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' was not found.
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099:
>   =============================================================== 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Domain.GetAssembly(IAssemblyName assemblyName,
>   BindingOptions bindingOptions) 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj :
>   error PS0099: at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyRefDeclaration.^5YpB0scd(BindingOptions
>   _0) 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.MulticastAttributeTask.^SgrhoGlQ(AssemblyRefDeclaration
>   _0) 1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: at PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.MulticastAttributeTask.^+GwnKh4ZYHu3()
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Tasks.MulticastAttributeTask.Execute()
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.ExecutePhase(String phase)
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: at
>   PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.Execute()
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: at
>   PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.ExecuteProjects()
>   1>F:\TwinkyTalk\TwinkyTalk.csproj : error PS0099: at
>   PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation
>   projectInvocation).

I was unable to find any references to "'newtonsoft.json, version=4.5.0.0," in the project, not sure why it is looking for that.

I tried setting the "Build Host" PostSharp project property to managed but still got the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that while the exception was coming from PostSharp the remedy was updating all the NuGet packages.

Answer (score 6):

This usually can happen when some of the 3-rd party libraries reference an older version of the assembly (Newtonsoft.Json in this case). The problem is solved by specifying a binding redirect in your web.config/app.config file.

```
<dependentAssembly>
  <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral"/>
  <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.3.0" newVersion="6.0.3.0"/>
</dependentAssembly>
```

However, you also need to tell PostSharp where to look for binding redirect configuration. You can do this by setting *PostSharpHostConfigurationFile* property in your *.csproj file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <PostSharpHostConfigurationFile>web.config</PostSharpHostConfigurationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

There's another similar question on SO ([PostSharp AssemblyLoadException Autofac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23968550/postsharp-assemblyloadexception-autofac)), and a [relevant blog post](http://crosscuttingconcerns.com/PostSharp-and-bindingRedirect).

Comment: Hi Alex, I appreciate your help. I tried both methods but they didn't solve the problem for me, but they lead me in the right direction. I've added the final resolution in case anyone else has the same problem.