# postsharp won't compile after update to v4.1.4

Tags: postsharp

After updating to version 4.1.4 the following message shows when i try to compile.
The issue seems to be quite different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25798212/assemblyloadexception-in-postsharp-on-release-build) and i cannot figure out how to fix it.
Any help? Thank you.

Error   2   System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Impossibile trovare una parte del percorso 'C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\4.1.4\bin.Release.NetFramework,v2.0'.
   in System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   in System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
   in System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String originalUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`1 resultHandler, Boolean checkHost)
   in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern)
   in ^GdBbaAyAGz1E.^G6rxpdCt(^siEGsPw0R2vn _0, MultiDictionary`2& _1, MultiDictionary`2& _2, Dictionary`2& _3)
   in ^GdBbaAyAGz1E.^6VjBNoXf(String _0, ^siEGsPw0R2vn _1, ^siEGsPw0R2vn _2)
   in ^GdBbaAyAGz1E.^+UuB/Ixy(String _0, Lazy`1 _1, Lazy`1[] _2)
   in ^GdBbaAyAGz1E.^/SEVAGft(String _0, String _1, Lazy`1 _2, Dictionary`2 _3)
   in ^GdBbaAyAGz1E.^i5Uba8Lq(Project _0)
   in PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.Domain.LoadBindingMaps(Project project)
   in PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.^63o9P8x3(Domain _0, ProjectConfiguration[] _1, ProjectInvocationParameters _2)
   in PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.^63o9P8x3(Domain _0, ProjectInvocationParameters _1)
   in PostSharp.Sdk.Extensibility.Project.CreateInstance(Domain domain, ProjectInvocation projectInvocation)
   in PostSharp.Hosting.PostSharpObject.InvokeProject(ProjectInvocation projectInvocation)
   in PostSharp.Hosting.Program.ExecuteImpl()   ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update your VSIX extension to the latest version (4.0.38). We have recently had an issue that VSIX extension downloaded prerelease version of PostSharp (4.1.4) which had critical issue. We have pulled NuGet package down and fixed the VSIX, so that it correctly downloads stable versions of PostSharp.